# How can I wrap failed model validation result of an ASP.NET Core 5 Web API controller action into another class and return response as OK

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core, clean-architecture, asp.net-core-middleware

I have ASP.NET Web API controller with some actions (methods). Let's say something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> SavePerson([FromBody]PersonDto person)
{
    await _mediatr.Send(new SavePerson.Command(person));
    return Ok();
}
```

and the **PersonDto** looks something like this:

```
public record PersonDto([Required, MinLength(3)]string Name, int? Age);
```

When I call my Web API action 'SavePerson' with invalid person data (Name.Length < 3 and etc...), ASP.NET Core model binding validation interrupts the execution and returns 400 (Bad Request) as it should. When I pass valid person data, it works fine.

My questions are:

1. How can I catch this model binding validation result (400 Bad Request) and transform it into different format, so our front-end developers will be happy?
2. Should I validate my DTOs (PersonDto) in Web API layer or it's better to validate it in MediatR command handler? I'm trying to adhere Uncle Bob's Clean Architecture. I have Domain, Application, Infrastructure, Web API. And my MediatR CQRS handlers are placed in the Application layer.

Comment: Front end developers will not be happy if you suppress 400 errors by converting them into 200s. Instead, just include error information in the body which is what Web API does by default.

Comment: @Aluan Haddad. In fact I told our front-end developers that there are errors I cannot wrap into the class they expect. Errors like 503 Service Unavailable are generated by IIS as far as I know. But they insisted to wrap errors, so here I am.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Jason Taylor's [Clean Architecture](https://github.com/jasontaylordev/CleanArchitecture) approach. Instead of using attribute validation, use FluentValidation:

```cs
public class CreatePersonCommandValidator : AbstractValidator<SavePerson.Command>
{
    public CreatePersonCommandValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(v => v.Title)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Title is required.")
            .MinimumLength(200).WithMessage("Title at least should have 3 characters.");
    }
}
```

Use MediatR behavior to perform validation and translate errors into a validation exception:

```cs
public class ValidationBehaviour<TRequest, TResponse> : IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>
        where TRequest : IRequest<TResponse>
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IValidator<TRequest>> _validators;

    public ValidationBehaviour(IEnumerable<IValidator<TRequest>> validators)
    {
        _validators = validators;
    }

    public async Task<TResponse> Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate<TResponse> next)
    {
        if (_validators.Any())
        {
            var context = new ValidationContext<TRequest>(request);

            var validationResults = await Task.WhenAll(_validators.Select(v => v.ValidateAsync(context, cancellationToken)));
            var failures = validationResults.SelectMany(r => r.Errors).Where(f => f != null).ToList();

            if (failures.Count != 0)
                throw new ValidationException(failures);
        }
        return await next();
    }
}
```

Validation exception:

```cs
public class ValidationException : Exception
{
    public ValidationException()
        : base("One or more validation failures have occurred.")
    {
        Errors = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
    }

    public ValidationException(IEnumerable<ValidationFailure> failures)
        : this()
    {
        Errors = failures
            .GroupBy(e => e.PropertyName, e => e.ErrorMessage)
            .ToDictionary(failureGroup => failureGroup.Key, failureGroup => failureGroup.ToArray());
    }

    public IDictionary<string, string[]> Errors { get; }
}
```

And finally, implement an exception filter or exception handling middleware to catch that exception and return the desired response:

```cs
public class ApiExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{

    private readonly IDictionary<Type, Action<ExceptionContext>> _exceptionHandlers;

    public ApiExceptionFilterAttribute()
    {
        // Register known exception types and handlers.
        _exceptionHandlers = new Dictionary<Type, Action<ExceptionContext>>
        {
            { typeof(ValidationException), HandleValidationException }
        };
    }

    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        HandleException(context);

        base.OnException(context);
    }

    private void HandleException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        Type type = context.Exception.GetType();
        if (_exceptionHandlers.ContainsKey(type))
        {
            _exceptionHandlers[type].Invoke(context);
            return;
        }

        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            HandleInvalidModelStateException(context);
            return;
        }

        HandleUnknownException(context);
    }

    private void HandleValidationException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        var exception = context.Exception as ValidationException;

        //var details = new ValidationProblemDetails(exception.Errors)
        //{
            //Type = "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1"
        //};


        context.Result = Returns your response type //new BadRequestObjectResult(details);

        context.ExceptionHandled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Automatic 400 bad request responses is enabled by default. To disable it use the following code in Startup `ConfigureServices` method:

```
services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
{
     options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
});
```

Then you can handle invalid model states manually like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> SavePerson([FromBody]PersonDto person)
{
    if(!ModelState.IsValid)
        return BadRequest(ModelState);// or what ever you want
    await _mediatr.Send(new SavePerson.Command(person));
    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this 'options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;' might be handy one day.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform ModelState.isValid() in the biginig of your Api method and return a BadRequestResult() if the model is invalid. You can can return the validation errors along with BadRequestResult.

You need to get validation errors from model state and fill your custom error object. This way your customers can see more meaningful errors.